# Portrait video gets cut off in landscape mode on Android React Native

Tags: android, react-native

My issue is when a video that was recorded in portrait mode is rotated to landscape, the video gets cut off and I have to scroll to see the rest of the frame. Currently the video is in a webview, view with styling that sets width and height to 100%. This is specific to android as ios seems to handle rotating appropriately.

Any ideas?
[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dydaV.jpg)

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KTaG.jpg)